# Could not find aapt2-8.0.2-9289358-windows.jar

Tags: java, android, gradle

when i run my application i get this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@4e59c9e of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
   > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@4e59c9e of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration2'.
         > Failed to transform aapt2-8.0.2-9289358-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.0.2-9289358) to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
            > Could not find aapt2-8.0.2-9289358-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.0.2-9289358).
              Searched in the following locations:
                  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.0.2-9289358/aapt2-8.0.2-9289358-windows.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

evrything is ok i update gradle an evrything but problame is still going when i run elomatur

Comment: The mentioned link to `aapt2-8.0.2-9289358-windows.jar` is correct and fully working here. Make sure your network is full functional and the link works. If it still doesn't work you can try to delete the cached files and force redownload. Local cache: `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/aapt2-proto/8.0.1-9289358`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem , this solution worked for me, just go to `settings.gradle`, and reorder repositories so they look like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

** this worked on gradle plugin 8.0.2 and gradle version 8.0 and JDK 17**

Answer (score 0):

For me it was resolved by deleting C:\Users<user>.gradle\caches